# What to do if Metamask doesn't show a deposit because it's an "internal transaction"?

Tags: metamask, etherscan, error

This is a follow-up on the question "Do all transactions show in Metamask wallet?" from Sky Hayward, in which Sky asked about transactions that show up as successful on etherscan, yet the ether doesn't appear in one's Metamask wallet.  Ismael answered, "Unfortunately internal transactions are not displayed by Metamask.  See this report: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/565 .  Sadly, the link shows that this has been a known issue since 2016!

It seems like this makes Metamask unusable.  I tried to withdraw some ETH from an account at Blockfi to my wallet.  Blockfi apparently sent the ETH as a "smart contract", and for some reason it shows up as an "Internal txns" on etherscan.  Supposedly it was successful.  But Metamask doesn't acknowledge it.

I understand that theoretically, the ETH are now owned by my wallet, regardless of what Metamask thinks.
But I can't use them because Metamask doesn't credit them to me.  What do I do?

Comment: Do you have transaction hash? Even if Metamask doesn't show the transfer the balance should be correct and match the one in a block explorer like Etherscan.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I'm mining ETH and using MetaMask as my wallet Will they try and fix this "bug" or just let us suffer?

Answer (score 0):

So the same thing happened to me and I did an audit.  Like you say I cannot see the receipt in my transaction history, but if I net out all my transactions the balance it give me is the exact amount off that my withdrawal was for.

So the funds were received and usuable, just not properly recorded in the metamask transaction history.

Very annoying when trying to prepare for taxes and track portfolio progress.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to view all internal transactions for a specific metamask address, I highly recommend you check out Alchemy Notify.

After creating a free account, you can use their API key and Notify tools to set up webhook notifications for all transaction activity (including internal transactions) at a specific address.

Here's a link to their docs: https://docs.alchemyapi.io/alchemy/guides/using-webhooks#address-activity

I've also found their discord super helpful in answering any questions I have :)